# Swift, use framework with nibs / core data / icloud for use in different apps?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I'm quite new to swift and I'm building a small project.

In Obj C, I created a framework to share drawing code, I'm having difficulty visualing how my new project idea will fit into this approach.

I want to create some very similar apps, there will be different color schemes and different data.
I'd also like to create nibs in the framework or whatever I end up using.

But pretty much everything else will be the same, I also need to use core data and icloud, something I never used in Obj C.

So can I do this in a framework? I'd never added nibs before, just code.

Is frameworks the right mechanism for this approach?

Comment: You can add nibs on your framework I've done it before

Comment: Are there any alternatives or is the best approach ?

Comment: I'm not that adept myself but the alternative is to code it manually by calculating the size yourself. Which is better by my thinking, but it'd be easier if you use nibs